# find the index of a string ignoring cases

Tags: python

I have a string that I need to find index in a list ignoring cases.

```
MG
['ADMISSION' ,'Colace','100','mg', 'b.i.d.' , 'insulin','Lente','12']
```

I want to find the index of MG in the following line as a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can ignore the cases by converting the total list and the item you want to search into lowercase.

```
>>> to_find = 'MG'
>>> old_list =  ['ADMISSION' ,'Colace','100','mg', 'b.i.d.' , 'insulin','Lente','12']
>>> new_list = [item.lower() for item in old_list]
>>> new_list.index(to_find.lower())
3
```

Answer (score 21):

One of the more elegant ways you can do this is to use a generator:

```
>>> list = ['ADMISSION' ,'Colace','100','mg', 'b.i.d.' , 'insulin','Lente','12']
>>> next(i for i,v in enumerate(list) if v.lower() == 'mg')
3
```

The above code makes a generator that yields the index of the next case insensitive occurrence of `mg` in the list, then invokes `next()` once, to retrieve the first index. If you had several occurrences of `mg` in the list, calling `next()` repeatedly would yield them all.

This also has the benefit of being marginally less expensive, since an entire lower cased list need not be created; only as much of the list is processed as needs to be to find the next match.

Comment: I think `if v.lower() == 'mg'` would be both simpler and faster.  BTW, `.next()` is less forward-compatible than `next(generator_here)`.

Comment: @DSM Ah yes, don't know what I was thinking there. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @Asad I don't follow the syntax. How to use this to insert an item into the middle of the list?

Answer (score 1):

Same as first but I don't think there is need to create a new and old list if you are only interested in the index

```
>>> search_term ="MG"
>>> my_list = ['ADMISSION' ,'Colace','100','mg', 'b.i.d.' , 'insulin','Lente','12']
>>> [item.lower() for item in my_list ].index(search_term .lower())
3
```